# Flutter Column with ListView and more Widgets above it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i'm trying a simple title -> search box -> listview thing, but can;t figure out how to fill the screen without tripping the horrible overflow error.

```
body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text('title', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
......
TextField(textfield_settings),
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6, // the part i want to get rid of and have a flexible height, based on the total screen size and the other widgets
            child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {})
    )
)
```

I Basically want the SingleChildScrollView containing the ListView.builder to take up the rest of the space left in the body.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Expanded` on ListView

```dart
body: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text(
        'title',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      TextField(),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return Text("sds");
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: worked splendidly, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore more about [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)